# Get Same Quarter Revenue From Previous Year

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have a set of data that is divided by the department, fiscal year, fiscal quarter and finally total amount, similar to below.

```
+---------------------------------+------------+---------------+-------------+
|            Department           | FISCALYEAR | FISCALQUARTER | TotalAmount |
+---------------------------------+------------+---------------+-------------+
| Internal Medicine - Dermatology |       2018 |             2 | 50.00       |
| Internal Medicine - Dermatology |       2018 |             4 | 75.00       |
| Internal Medicine - Dermatology |       2019 |             1 | 135.00      |
| Internal Medicine - Dermatology |       2019 |             2 | 75.00       |
| Internal Medicine - Dermatology |       2019 |             3 | 185.00      |
| Internal Medicine - Dermatology |       2019 |             4 | 84.00       |
| Internal Medicine - Dermatology |       2020 |             1 | 85.00       |
| Internal Medicine - Dermatology |       2020 |             2 | 10.00       |
+---------------------------------+------------+---------------+-------------+
```

How would I add a column to get the total amount from the previous year/quarter?
For instance fiscal year 2020, fiscal quarter 2 would show 75.00.

The tough part is that some quarters don't have any data, so there are gaps.

I have attempted a LAG() window function, but have difficulties on specifying the offset since it is not a standard offset.

Any help/ideas would be great.

Comment: So what would your expect result be for fiscal year 2019, fiscal quarter 3 look back to the prior year? Null, zero, blank?

Comment: Preferably a NULL value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e8516f1bd583fb291c7ad58b5cd23aaf)?

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#YourTable', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #YourTable; 

CREATE TABLE #YourTable(
   Department    VARCHAR(33) NOT NULL
  ,FISCALYEAR    INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,FISCALQUARTER INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,TotalAmount   NUMERIC(7,2) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO #YourTable(Department,FISCALYEAR,FISCALQUARTER,TotalAmount) VALUES ('Internal Medicine - Dermatology',2018,2,50.00);
INSERT INTO #YourTable(Department,FISCALYEAR,FISCALQUARTER,TotalAmount) VALUES ('Internal Medicine - Dermatology',2018,4,75.00);
INSERT INTO #YourTable(Department,FISCALYEAR,FISCALQUARTER,TotalAmount) VALUES ('Internal Medicine - Dermatology',2019,1,135.00);
INSERT INTO #YourTable(Department,FISCALYEAR,FISCALQUARTER,TotalAmount) VALUES ('Internal Medicine - Dermatology',2019,2,75.00);
INSERT INTO #YourTable(Department,FISCALYEAR,FISCALQUARTER,TotalAmount) VALUES ('Internal Medicine - Dermatology',2019,3,185.00);
INSERT INTO #YourTable(Department,FISCALYEAR,FISCALQUARTER,TotalAmount) VALUES ('Internal Medicine - Dermatology',2019,4,84.00);
INSERT INTO #YourTable(Department,FISCALYEAR,FISCALQUARTER,TotalAmount) VALUES ('Internal Medicine - Dermatology',2020,1,85.00);
INSERT INTO #YourTable(Department,FISCALYEAR,FISCALQUARTER,TotalAmount) VALUES ('Internal Medicine - Dermatology',2020,2,10.00);

SELECT a.Department, a.FISCALYEAR, a.FISCALQUARTER, 
       a.TotalAmount, b.TotalAmount AS PriorYearQuarterTotalAmount
FROM #YourTable a
LEFT JOIN #YourTable b ON a.Department = b.Department
                     AND a.FISCALYEAR - 1 = b.FISCALYEAR
                     AND a.FISCALQUARTER = b.FISCALQUARTER
```

Comment: This worked like a charm, the only change I had to make was: AND a.FISCALYEAR - 1 = b.FISCALYEAR

Comment: I figured that out too after creating and running against test data. I have corrected my answer for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an inline query:

```
select 
    t.*,
    (
        select t1.TotalAmount 
        from mytable t1 
        where t1.FiscalQuarter = t.FiscalQuarter and t1.FiscalYear = t.FiscalYear - 1
    ) lastTotalAmount
from mytable t
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have data for every year, use window functions:

```
SELECT a.Department, a.FISCALYEAR, a.FISCALQUARTER, 
       a.TotalAmount,
       LAG(a.TotalAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY a.Department, a.FISCALQUARTER ORDER BY a.FISCALYEAR) AS PriorYearQuarterTotalAmount
FROM a;
```

Window functions generally result in the fastest queries and are more concise than alternatives.